# HTML Entities with Knockout

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

How can I output HTML Entities in fields that are bound to a variable in the viewModel? I would like to display an HTML Entity like ← (`&larr;`) in a field bound to a `span` in the HTML. Unfortunately, the HTML is escaped, so the browser displays &larr; instead of the symbol.

Fiddle with an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/nwinkler/KES2j/

JavaScript:

```
var data = { value : '&larr;'};

var viewModel = {
    field: ko.mapping.fromJS(data)
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

HTML:

```
<p>HTML: &larr;</p>
<p>Knockout: <span data-bind='text: field.value'></span></p>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the `html` binding for something like this one.  It would look like:

```
<p>Knockout: <span data-bind='html: field.value'></span></p>
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/KES2j/1/

Comment: It's important to realize that if you switch from text: to html: you potentially create a security problem. You should make sure that the value of field.value cannot be manipulated by users of your application. Otherwise, you may open yourself up to a CSRF attack.

Comment: How can I bind html with the options binding?