# Setting HTML tag attribute with value containing HTML entity, via knockoutjs

Tags: html, knockout.js, html-entities

How can I set the title attribute of an HTML tag via knockoutjs in a way that will cause any HTML entities in the tag contents to be evaluated and displayed (i.e. not escaped)?

Example:

```
<div data-bind="attr: { title: titleObservable }"></div>
```

In the above example, if titleObservable contains an HTML entity, it will not be rendered, rather the entity name will be displayed. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TMSHB/1/) for a working example. Notice that when you hover over the div, the title text contains &#39 instead of the apostrophe symbol.

I know that when setting the contents of an HTML tag with the knockoutjs text binding that HTML is escaped for security reasons (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225583/html-entities-with-knockout)). I am assuming that this is what is happening to the entity in my title attribute. I also know that I can just embed the apostrophe directly into the title attribute, but I would like to know if there is a way that I can do this with the HTML entities (due to certain limitations on the project I am working on).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to use HTML entities within Javascript (which Knockout bindings use) is through `innerHTML`. All other access to the DOM uses UTF-8 text.

I suggest that you update your code to use plain text within your model and only use HTML entities within actual HTML documents. But if you cannot do so, you can use a custom binding handler that converts from HTML to text before setting the DOM property. Here's one I just made that sets the title.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myTitle = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var d = document.createElement('div');
        d.innerHTML = value;
        element.title = d.innerText;
    }
};
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/TMSHB/2/

Comment: The answer, while it works, doesn't make sense, because 1. you must html-encode certain characters like the ampersand sign, 2. jquery is also javascript and doesn't have this problem